# How to add ParseLoginUI to Android Studio Project?

Tags: android, parse-platform

First let me say it would be optimal if they'd just make a mavencentral package for this.

I used the directions in the readme at the github

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android

1. Clone this repository onto your machine.
2. Fetch the Facebook SDK Git submodule by running the following command in your local
   ParseUI-Android repository directory: 
      git submodule update --init
   --recursive
3. Import this repository's projects with Android Studio or Eclipse.

   1. For Android Studio, just import your local ParseUI-Android repository directory.

I used **File->Import Project** and selected the **settings.gradle** in the top level and when it builds I get:

*Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.*

Any suggestions how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing:

> Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Is not very helpful. Running

```
./gradlew  tasks --info
```

Yielded more information.  In most of the cases it was that gradle couldn't find the location of the build.gradle.

To fix that I changed my settings.gradle to be the following:

```
include ':app', ':ParseLoginUI' , ':facebook-sdk:facebook'
include ':app:libs:ParseUI-Android'

project(':ParseLoginUI').projectDir = new File('__PATH_TO_YOUR_CHECKED_OUT__/ParseUI-Android/ParseLoginUI')
project(':facebook-sdk:facebook').projectDir = new File('__PATH_TO_YOUR_CHECKED_OUT__/ParseUI-Android/facebook-sdk/facebook')
```

Then I found I needed to update many of the versions of support library in the ParseUI-Android and the facebook-sdk.

And finally add the following to my gradle.properties

```
# Copied from ParseUI-Android/gradle.properties
ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=8
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=20
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=20
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=20
```

You can see the changes I made to the two git repos in the following changes:
[https://github.com/bdbaddog/facebook-android-sdk/commit/e80528f7b2375c0c12d3f9a6d743dbb40b78b770][facebook sdk changes]

[https://github.com/bdbaddog/ParseUI-Android/commit/98b617bf598abcee73d7b7bb0df57d49f10af82d][ParseUI-Android changes]

I'm fairly certain that's all the changes I made. Please try and let me know.